# Post JSON to Rest Spring 4 service

Tags: json, post, spring-rest

I am trying to post a complex/nested json to Rest Spring4 using PostMan rest client but objectMapper.readValue returns null.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginuser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public @ResponseBody
            Status Login(@RequestBody String userdata) {        
                try {
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    LoginData theUser = objectMapper.readValue(userdata, LoginData.class);


        String userdata contains Json string but  objectMapper.readValue returns null.
        JSON {"LoginData":{"id":"1",    "username":"kashmir1","password":"kashmir2"}}


        POJO:
        public class LoginData  implements Serializable{
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue
            @Column(name = "id")
              @JsonProperty("id")
            private String id;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            and soon for username and password
```

Please provide inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer :
follow below lines instead of directly accessing required node

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class)   ;
JsonNode userNode=rootNode.path("LoginData");
LoginData theUser = objectMapper.treeToValue(userNode, LoginData.class);
System.out.println("In Login"+theUser.getUsername());
```